# Is it possible to let mypy check that attribute exists in at least one union item (instead of each union item)?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-3.10

I'm trying to apply `mypy` on a large codebase that already has type annotations (which are checked by PyCharm). When running `mypy`, I get a bazzilion errors like:

```
error: Item "Bar" of "Union[Foo, Bar]" has no attribute "foo_func"
```

This is because `mypy` checks that the attribute `foo_func` exists in ***each*** union member, as described here:
https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list.html#check-that-attribute-exists-in-each-union-item-union-attr.

To avoid being overloaded with error messages like this, I want to modify the behavior of `mypy` such that it checks that the attribute `foo_func` exists in ***at least one*** union member.

Of course, I can add assertions in the code to tell `mypy` which type the object specifically is. But for now, I'm just looking for a way to modify the behavior of `mypy` itself.

Is this possible?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible, at least. This means exactly the following: your value `x` may be either `Foo` or `Bar`, so `x.foo_func` is invalid. You have no guarantees that it is actually `Foo` - you need an assertion, `cast` or proper type hint for function where `x` is created. You may need `overload` for this. You cannot say "at least one of union items has this attribute, so everything is fine": `mypy` is used exactly to locate edge cases where your assumption about type does not hold. Suppose you have method returning `x | None` and don't check for None - do you really want this silenced?

Comment: @SUTerliakov, I understand you point. But my goal is to improve this large codebase *gradually*. This means that I configure `mypy` in the least strict way and *gradually* increase its strictness. So to answer your question: *'Do you really want this silenced?'* => Yes, I do want this silenced *for now*. Later on, I can de-silence it.

Comment: Augh, actually the link in your question is the answer. You can disable "union-attr" error code to ignore exactly this kind of errors.

Comment: How exactly? Should I add a line like this to `mypy.ini`:
`union-attr = False`
Or perhaps this:
`union_attr = False` or something else?

Comment: In config file it should be `disable_error_code = union-attr`, probably.